24.04 LTS fails upgrade missing libnettle.so.8
When Software Updater offered 24.04 LTS, I allowed it to install.  When I came back, there was just a black screen with a cursor for a few hours, so I cycled power.  When it came "up", a black screen asked for my login, so I did.  It prints a few URLs, says I should turn on "Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications", 704 updates can be applied immediately, Enable ESM Apps to receive future security updates, flatpak error loading libnettle.so.8
How do I recover my system at some LTS revision?

Forget the EMS for now, did you allow the other updates?  Which desktop were you running?  What video hardware do you have and what drivers were you using? A little more information would help us make better suggestions.

I tried sudo apt update and http failed for same lib.

I was running the standard gnome stuff.  HP Mobo built in video.

We need to see the complete, accurate error message. Since you cannot access the desktop to use screenshot, take a clear, readable photo of your sudo apt update output using your phone.

This question is similar to: How to start Ubuntu in Console mode. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is why did you put out a defective upgrade and how do I recover.

sudo apt  update dies in http with missing lib libnettle.so.8, as I said.  Do you really need a picture?
I see there are several files like this on my disk, in snap or flatpak subdirs.  Could I put one of them into a more prominent dir?

I see on my WIn11 WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04: this, apparently brough in by snap:
6833      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Mar 24  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8 -> libnettle.so.8.4
6834    276 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root       281000 Mar 24  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8.4
What file is right for 24.04 LTS?

I guess I can get 24.04 on a pen drive and reinstall it, then reinstall all my previously installed apps and system settings, but maybe you guys want to find out why 24.04 does not install cleanly, and save me from this?

https://photos.app.goo.gl/3vjKfSswVTdqPbvt8 Photo of 24.04 boot

I installed 24.04 in parallel from a pen drive, and it thinks my old system is still 22.04.  Apparently it carved a new partition, but whatever!  No help on new title!

Just fyi, my update crashed for the same reason. I did not find any way how to get it back on track.

I ran into the same problem, here's what I did in order to fix it.
First of all, through GRUB I found a kernel version that could still boot and I was welcomed by a root shell.
Then I connected to internet with:
root# ip addr add 192.168.1.10/24 dev MY-DEVICE #add ip address
root# route add default gw 192.168.1.1 #add gateway (router)
root# echo "8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf #set DNS

At this point, I tried to run apt install --fix-broken, which let me kindly now that I was missing the libnettle8 package; I installed it manually with
root# wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/679187946/libnettle8_3.9.1-2_amd64.deb
root# dpkg -i libnettle8_3.9.1-2_amd64.deb

After that, apt install --fix-broken worked again; I had to manually fix some other errors (uninstalling a couple packages with apt uninstall), then updated again everything with:
root# apt update && apt upgrade -y
root# apt dist-upgrade
root# apt install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
root# reboot

I think I won't upgrade again until 2029.
